# Using IMPORTHTML for multi row import instead reaching max 50 query limit

Tags: google-sheets

I was able to use the following format to check if an item was in stock or not based on the products web address/ID column:

```
=IF(RegExMatch(IMPORTHTML("http://www.example.com/product_info.php?products_id=20", 
 "list",4),"Product not found"),"Out of stock","In stock")
```

This works fine except that my sheet is approximately 1000 rows.. and about 20,000 on another one because each row is an attribute of the same product id.

So to begin a little easier with the sheet that is only 1000 there is still a limit of 50 queries per sheet I have found out. I am trying to figure out how I can do all the queries within one formula and then parse it which I have been told is possible but doing something like

```
=IF(RegExMatch(IMPORTHTML("D1:D1000", "list",4),"Product not found"),
 "Out of stock","In stock")
```

This I thought would return an array but instead just prints out I think the last returned result.

So I am not sure if it is possible to use `IMPORTHTML` to do what I am hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

**`IMPORTHTML`** (or any other formula from import cluster family except `IMPORTRANGE`) is not able to intake arrayed range.

workarounds are to either use multiple spreadsheets and then import all your stuff with `IMPORTRANGE` or (if possible) import all data from example.com website with one `IMPORTHTML` or `IMPORTXML` formula to some sheet and then `INDEX` out stuff you need to your main master sheet

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit how that would work? How would I be ble to use IMPORTHTML to import all data with only one importhtml?

Comment: @Sackling like I said `(if possible)` meaning it depends on data eg. to elaborate it... most of ppl trying to import specific stuff from web (lets say 50x every 2nd cell from table) and they hit the 50 quota. instead they could use one `IMPORTHTML` (or `=importxml("url", "//*")`) to import whole table and then index out stuff they need in the main sheet - thats what I meant and not sure if thats also your case or not because you didn't provide specific example/sample of your scraping. in either case `IMPORTHTML("D1:D1000" ...` will never work

Comment: Gotcha I don't think that would be possible because it has to reload each webpage with each product id. I think I will rethink this and maybe do a timed export from my webpage back end that can be sent to a single table. Thanks for your help though!